# Why do I get a "-[__SwiftValue MKCoordinateValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance" error

Tags: swift, mapkit, core-location

I am getting the following error message when I run my Swift code;

> 2019-11-11 15:59:58.737125+0000 GoSiteUK[53192:1746609] -[__SwiftValue MKCoordinateValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000037c720
>   2019-11-11 15:59:58.741797+0000 GoSiteUK[53192:1746609] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__SwiftValue MKCoordinateValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000037c720'

This code previously worked fine some weeks ago but is now not working with nothing changed.

```
let destinationPlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 50.0, longitude: 1.0))
let destinationMapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: destinationPlacemark)

destinationMapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: [
    MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey : MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving,
    MKLaunchOptionsMapCenterKey : CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.0, longitude: 0.5)
] )
```

I expect the Maps app to open and no error messages.

Comment: What do you get if you change `MKLaunchOptionsMapCenterKey : CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.0, longitude: 0.5)` to `MKLaunchOptionsMapCenterKey : NSValue(mkCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.0, longitude: 0.5))` ?

Comment: It works! No error message! Why does this work? And thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure about that, but some people reports the behavior of bridging `NSValue` has changed recently in Swift. You may need to use `NSValue` explicitly to store some value types.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mklaunchoptionsmapcenterkey It's written there that it needs a `NSValue`.